# Scanf understandings

Tags: c++, c, scanf

I am going through some examples in a book I have and I have come to something I've never seen before nor understand:

```
scanf("%d-%d-%d-%d-%d", &prefix, &group, &publisher, &item, &check_digit);
```

This code is part of a program that asks the user to enter their ISBN number of a book and later on breaks down the ISBN into `Prefix = x`, `Group = y`, etc..

I have NEVER seen the hypens between the `%d`'s. Does anyone see any point in this??

Thanks

Comment: You really, really, **really** should check the return value from `scanf()`: in this case anyhting other than 5, probably, indicates an input error. `if (scanf(...) != 5) /* error */;`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"Pattern matching". If the input doesn't fit the specified pattern (also called format), it fails. So if you input anything else than `INT-INT-INT-INT-INT` (where `INT` is a placeholder for an integer you input), the input would be considered invalid.

Answer (score 3):

The represent the actual parts of the string to be scanned.

For example your `"%d-%d-%d-%d-%d"` would work with something like `"10-56-666-1-90"`.

Answer (score 1):

It parses 5 numbers (matched by `%d`) with a dash between each two (the `-`). Each number is saved to a variable passed in as argument. See the manual for `scanf` and `printf` under `Conversions`.

Answer (score 1):

`scanf` takes a format string, so it's about what input it expects to see for input. The hyphens are for actual hyphens in the input. `1-2-3-4-5-6` would be valid input for this call, and give you `prefix=1`, `group=2`, etc.